# White spaces in Theano arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, theano

I just started playing around with Theano and I got surprised by the result of this code.

```
from theano import *
import theano.tensor as T
a = T.vector()
out = a + a ** 10
f = function([a], out)
print(f([0, 1, 2]))
```

Using python3 I get:

```
array([    0.,     2.,  1026.])
```

The array itself is correct, it contains the right values, however the printed output is odd. I would expect something like this:

```
array([0, 2, 1026])
```

or

```
array([0.0, 2.0, 1026.0])
```

Why it is so? What are the extra white spaces? Shall I be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're printing is a [`numpy.ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). By default they format themselves like this when printed.

The output array is a floating point array because, by default, Theano uses floating point tensors.

If you want to use integer tensors then you need to specify a `dtype`:

```
a = T.vector(dtype='int64')
```

Or use a bit of syntactic sugar:

```
a = T.lvector()
```

Compare your output with the output of the following:

```
print numpy.array([0, 2, 1026], dtype=numpy.float64)
print numpy.array([0, 2, 1026], dtype=numpy.int64)
```

You can change the default printing options of numpy using [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know about  `numpy.set_printoptions`, nice tip!